# Finding prime numbers in a range

Tags: optimization, c, primes

Finding the prime numbers between two given integers in the minimum number of comparisons:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int i,n,count,n1,n2;
    printf("Enter n1 and n2:");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    scanf("%d",&n2);
    n=n1;
    int c=0; //variable to store number of comparisions (number of times while() runs)
    for(n=n1;n<=n2;n1++,n=n1)
    {
        count=0; //number of factors found
        i=2;
        while((n>0)&&(i<=sqrt(n))) //condition for minimum comparisions
        {
            printf("\n\t%d",c++);//printing the comparision number
            if(n%i==0)
            {
                count++;
                n/=i;
            }
            else i++;
        }
        if(count==0)
            printf("\n%d",n1);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found some things that might help you improve your code:

### Strive for portable code

Several of the features of this code are either platform-specific or compiler-specific or both.  Specifically, `#include <conio.h>`, `clrscr()`, and `getch()` are all non-standard.  Instead consider portable replacements.  For instance you could use this instead of `clrscr()`:

```
putchar('\f');
```

Or possibly this:

```
for (int lines=40; lines; --lines)
    putchar('\n');
```

Alternatively, one could eliminate it entirely, which is what I've done in my modified version of your code.

### Follow standard declaration of `main`

Your compiler may allow you to declare `void main()` but that construction is technically only valid for what are called "non-hosted" environments, e.g. one in which you are not running Windows.  For that reason, you should use the standard `int main()` instead.  Note that you don't need to explicitly provide a `return 0;` at the end of main -- it's created implicitly by the compiler.

### Whitespace improves readability

Allofyourwordsarecrammedtogether.  Inserting some spaces in your lines will make them much easier to read.  For example, instead of this:

```
while((n>0)&&(i<=sqrt(n)))
```

try this:

```
while((n > 0) && (i <= sqrt(n)))
```

### Avoid `scanf` if you can

There are so many [well known problems with `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf) that you're usually better off avoiding it.  The usual approach is to read in user input into a string and then parse from there, in this case using something like `atoi()`.

### Eliminate redundant code

In this case, the line `n=n1;` is redundant since the initializer of the `for` loop does that again just two lines later.

### Consider reducing the scope of variables

The variable `n` is only used within the `for` loop, so you could declare it within the initializer:

```
for(int n=n1; n <= n2; n1++, n=n1)
```

### Use a `for` loop instead of `while`

Because the `i` variable is used only within the `while` loop, consider again reducing scope and turning that into a `for` loop:

```
for (int i=2;(n>0) && (i <= sqrt(n)); )
```

Even better, in that loop, the only use of `n` is for testing primes, so within it you can instead use a variable local to that loop.  I've used `t` (for `testing`):

```
for (int i=2, t=n; (t>0) && (i <= sqrt(t)); ) 
{
    printf("\t%d\n",c++);//printing the comparision number
    if(t%i==0)
    {
        count++;
        t/=i;
    }
    else i++;
}
```

This change also allows you to remove `n1` entirely and to simply use `n` everywhere that `n1` had been used.

### Improve your algorithm

Except for 2, all prime numbers are odd.  You can take advantage of that to reduce the number of comparisons:

```
for (int i=2, t=n; (t>0) && (i <= sqrt(t)); ) 
{
    printf("\t%d\n",c++);//printing the comparision number
    if(t%i==0)
    {
        count++;
        t/=i;     // better:  break;
    }
    else if (i==2) 
    {
        ++i;
    } else 
    {
        i += 2;
    }
}
```

However, once we discover that a number is not prime, why continue factoring it?  You can eliminate even more comparisons by replacing the line `t/=i` with `break` to break out of the enclosing `for` loop.

You can do a similar optimization on the outer loop, incrementing it by 2 each loop iteration once you assure that it is odd coming into the loop.

### Print newlines after rather than before

The code currently has `printf("\n%d", n1);` but the effect is that the last line printed doesn't actually end with `\n`.  Instead, re-arrange the two `printf` statements to that they both end rather than begin with `\n`.

## Results:

When I applied all of these to your code, I found that when I compute the primes from 500 to 1000, the original code made 6766 comparisons, while the optimized version made 1444.

Comment: `for (int lines=40; lines; --lines) putchar('\n');` really? Otherwise +1

Comment: @rolfl: hold on, I have to reload the paper roll in my TTY...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never really pondered enough to notice that all primes except two are odd. About scanf, do you mean to say that I should use something like gets() to read in the input as a string and then process it? And do for loops and while loops have any major difference in functionality that I should know of? WHITESPACES.

Comment: Also how exactly does atoi() function. Suppose I have a string like [1,2,+,3,-,4,5]. How does atoi() process the string? (PS: I actually need this for another one of my programs.)

Comment: I mean that you could use `getline` to fetch an entire line, and then use `atoi` to pull out an integer.  However if you feed it a string like `[1,2,+,3,-,4,5]` it will simply return '0'.

Answer (score 4):

Edward seemed to do a good job improving your code with your method of finding primes by checking divisibility by repeatedly dividing.

However, if your task is to quickly generate a list of primes in a large range, using a prime number sieve (e.g., [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or an optimized version like Sieve of Atkin or wheel sieves) is a better method.

Your method (as well as Edward's improvement by reducing redundant factors) takes \$O(N^{1.5})\$ to generate a list of primes from 1 to \$N\$ (\$\Sigma_{k=1}^{N} \sqrt{k} \sim O(N^{1.5}) \$).  The Sieve of Eratosthenes takes \$O(N)\$ time to generate the primes from 1 to \$N\$ and the optimized variations are asymptotically faster and can take \$O(N/\log \log N)\$, though you should note for \$N = 2^{32} \sim 4 \;{\rm billion}\$ (common maximum value for an unsigned int), \$\log \log N = 5\$ and for \$N = 2^{64} \sim 10^{19}\$(common maximum value of an unsigned long long int), \$\log \log N = 6\$).

If you need to find larger primes (for example doing RSA and requiring 512-bit primes) or primes in a very small range, its probably better by first checking divisibility against a list of small primes (first 1000 primes or so) and then switch to a probabilistic primality test like [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test) or [Baillie-PSW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie-PSW_primality_test).

Comment: I'll leave that for my final year of studies. Really not comfortable with standard algorithms. But thanks anyway.